# Preserving Hurwitz stability of block matrices with same eigenvalues of each block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, block-matrices, stability-theory, hurwitz-matrices

Let us assume that
$$A=-\text{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_m) +Q \text{ is Hurwitz},$$ where $d_i>0, \forall i\in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $Q\in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ is a possibly full matrix.

Can we deduce that (or under which conditions?)
$$\tilde A=-\text{blkdiag}(D_1,D_2,\ldots D_m)+ Q \otimes I_n \text{ is Hurwitz},$$
where $D_1\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is full matrix, while $D_2, \ldots D_m\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ are diagonal. Assume also that $\min( \mathrm{eigenspectrum}(D_i))=d_i$ and all eigenvalues of $D_i$ are positive, for all $i\in \{1,\ldots,m\}$.

In other words, both matrices $A$ and $\tilde A$ consist of diagonal matrices which share common eigenvalues. Note that $$\mathrm{eigenspectrum}(\text{blkdiag}(d_1,\ldots,d_m)) \subset \mathrm{eigenspectrum}(\text{diag}(D_1,D_2,\ldots D_m))$$ and $$\mathrm{eigenspectrum}(Q)\subset \mathrm{eigenspectrum}(Q \otimes I_n).$$ Intuitively, it seems that some properties should be preserved between both matrices $A$ and $\tilde A$.

Comment: Is it $I_n\otimes Q$ or $Q\otimes I_n$? Are you also sure of your first inclusion?

Comment: I made a mistake in the first inclusion. I rewrote it. It is $Q\otimes I_n$. The eigenvalues of the later are the same as the eigenvalues of $Q$ with multiplicity $n$.

Comment: Yes but it is not block diagonal.

Comment: you are right. I am sorry, I meant block matrices

Comment: Then that will not work. The block diagonal structure $I\otimes Q$ is much nicer in this respect. The fact you will have off-diagonal block entries in $\tilde A$ will perturb the eigenvalues of the whole matrix. Moreover, eigenvalues have terrible additive properties. I am also not even factoring in the fact that $D_1$ is not diagonal...

Comment: It is true that if the blockdiag matrix was identity, it would help a lot as we would have an explicit formula of the eigenvalues of the sum but now things become very complex. I pressume that for some values of D1, we can have the big matrix to be Hurwitz